# Как получить все столбцы соответсвующие заданому значению?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть такая таблица:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame([(0,1,1,1), (0,0,1,0), (1,1,0,0)], columns=['a','b','c','d'])
```

[image: df]

Нужно создать еще один столбец (например `f`), в котором будут перечислены столбцы, в которых оказалось значение `True`.

Что должно получиться:

```
b,c,d
c
a,b
```

```
dataframe.columns[dataframe.iloc[0] == 1]
```

Так можно вывести то, что нужно но для одного элемента.

Как это сделать без цикла для всего фрейма и красиво?

Comment: Не надо использовать скриншоты кода. Вы можете его скопировать в вопрос и отметить соответствующими тегами. Мало кто захочет перепечатывать ваш код руками, чтобы вам помочь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из векторизированных вариантов:

```
df["f"] = (pd
           .DataFrame(
               [df.columns.to_list()] * len(df),
               index=df.index, 
               columns=df.columns) 
           [df.eq(1)]
           .fillna("")
           .T
           .apply(",".join)
           .str.strip(","))
```

Результат:

```
In [170]: df
Out[170]:
   a  b  c  d      f
0  0  1  1  1  b,c,d
1  0  0  1  0      c
2  1  1  0  0    a,b
```

Answer (score 1):

вот так получилось без цикла и итерации:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(0,1,1,1), (0,0,1,0), (1,1,0,0)], columns=['a','b','c','d'])
df['f'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[x==1]).index.to_list(), axis=1)

 B [171]: df
Out[171]:
    a   b   c   d   f
0   0   1   1   1   [b, c, d]
1   0   0   1   0   [c]
2   1   1   0   0   [a, b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что это не очень хороший способ хранения информации. А для вывода результатов не нужно это сохранять в dataframe. Но вот как-то так у меня получилось:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([(0,1,1,1), (0,0,1,0), (1,1,0,0)], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df['f'] = [','.join(list(i[1][i[1] == 1].index)) for i in df.iterrows()]
```

Тут итерация по датафрейму, что не очень хорошо. Но как её избежать не придумал.